# Swift 2 How do I isolate resources in a series of NSMutableURLRequests?

Tags: swift2, closures, session-cookies, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest

Assume I've already logged to two accounts and have obtained unique session cookies for each.

When executing ViewController.run(), which uses nested closures, a series of 80 unique URL requests is made (40 for each of the two accounts) .

Though I'm able to make all 80 unique URL requests, somehow one account will sometimes make a request of a URL that only the other account should be making.

I'm pretty certain the resources between each account as well as each account's request are isolated. Both executions of `run()` construct their own instances of `Visit(_:)`, `URLVisitor(_:)` and `Request(_:)`.

Note: assume that neither account's username array contains a username that the other has in it's array.

**ViewController.swift**

```
func run(completion: () -> Void) {
    // 40 usernames appended to array
    var usernames: [String] = ["username1",..., username40]

    for username in usernames {
        let visit = Visit()
        visit.sessionCookie = sessionCookie
        visit.visitProfile(username) {
             NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5.0)
        }       
    }
}
```

**Visit.swift**

```
var contentsOfURL = NSString()
var sessionCookie = String()

func visitprofile(username: String, completion: () -> Void) {
    let url = "https://www.someurl.com/profile/\(username)"
    let encodedURL = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(
        NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet()),
    URL = NSURL(string: encodedURL!)    

    let vis = URLVisitor(URL: URL!)
    vis.sessionCookie = self.sessionCookie
    vis.execute {
        if vis.containsString(profileName) {
            print("\(profileName) visited: OK")
        } else {
            print("\(profileName) visited: FAIL")
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

**URLVisitor.swift**

```
var contentsOfURL = NSString()
var sessionCookie = String()
var URL = NSURL()

init(URL: NSURL) {
    self.URL = URL
}

func execute(completion: () -> Void) {
    let request = Request()
    request.sessionCookie = self.sessionCookie
    request.accessToken = self.accessToken
    request.sessionCookie = self.sessionCookie

    request.sendRequest(self.URL, completion: () -> Void) {
        self.sessionCookie = request.sessionCookie
        self.contentsOfURL = request.contentsOfURL
        completion()
    }
}
```

**Request.swift**: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate

```
var contentsOfURL = NSString()
var responseCookies = String()
var sessionCookie = String()

func sendRequest(URL: NSURL, completion: () -> Void) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    if sessionCookie != "" {
        config.HTTPCookieStorage = nil
        config.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.setValue(sessionCookie, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
            let response = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

            do {
                self.contentsOfURL = try NSString(contentsOfURL: URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            } catch{

            }

            if self.sessionCookie == "" {        
                self.sessionCookie = // obtained here during login
            }
        completion() 
    }
    task.resume()
}
```